# directive selector not matching dynamic (bound) classname or attribute

Tags: angular

I'm building a dynamic form following the [cookbook documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/dynamic-form.html)

In addition, I have a directive with the selector `input[type=signature]`.

If I use this in `dynamic-form-question.component.ts`:

```html
<input *ngSwitchCase="'signature'"
            [id]="question.attribs.name" 
            [formControlName]="question.attribs.name" 
            type="signature" 
            class="signature" />
```

my directive matches.

However, if I use

```html
<input *ngSwitchDefault
            class="form-control"
            [formControlName]="question.attribs.name"
            [id]="question.attribs.name"
            [ngClass]="question.attribs.class"
            [placeholder]="question.attribs.placeholder"
            [type]="question.attribs.type" />
```

where the `type.attribute` is bound, it's no dice.

likewise I tried the selector `input.signature` and `input.signature, input[type=signature]`, but they also don't work if the class or type attributes are bound.

Is this not supported, do I need to do something else to get this functionality?

Comment: @jonrsharpe thanks for the edits!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Directive selectors have to be static element names, attributes, or classes.
They need to be added statically do the components template.
Everything added dynamically in any way is not considered by Angular2.

The only workaround I know is to create the components at runtime (with static element names, attributes or classes) for directives and pipes to be created with them - like explained in [Equivalent of $compile in Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34784778/equivalent-of-compile-in-angular-2/37044960#37044960)